# Error in overlay - formula not vectorized

Tags: raster, r, overlay, function, vectorization

I've run into another error while trying to get my predictive model to work. My base model is basically done (extracting locational parameters from archaeological sites in an area, and calculating a predictive map for archaeological risk areas, containing `slope`, `tpi`, `tpi_15`, `aspect` and `distance` to water), but it is not as accurate as I'd like it to be. So I'm trying to assign different weights to the parameters (e.g. `distance` to water is more important than `aspect`), and that's where I'm stuck.

```
weights <- apply(X = sn_sf_bind, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x)
{sqrt(1/sd(x)*range(x)[2]-range(x)[1])})
```

`sn_sf_bind` is my table with the archaeological sites and assigned locational parameters, looks like this:

[image]

For this I don't get an error, but I don't know if it could be in there already.

The code that isn't working is this:

```
wba <- overlay(x = ter_par_big,
               fun=function(w,x,y,z){
                 return((v*weights[1])+
                          (w*weights[2])+
                          (x*weights[3])+
                          (y*weights[4])+
                          (z*weights[5]))},
               unstack = TRUE)
```

I've also tried this:

```
fw <- function(v,w,x,y,z){
  return((v*weights[1])+
           (w*weights[2])+
           (x*weights[3])+
           (y*weights[4])+
           (z*weights[5]))}

wba <- overlay(x = ter_par_big,
               fun=Vectorize(fw),
               unstack = TRUE)
```

But it didn't change anything, I'm still getting the same error:

```
Error in .overlayList(x, fun = fun, filename = filename, forcefun = forcefun,  : 
  cannot use this formula, probably because it is not vectorized
```

`ter_par_big` is my Raster Brick, consisting of 5 layers with the locational parameters for the overall area, it looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is `weights` a vector of length five? We can't compute it because we don't have your  data and you've not shown us it...

Comment: I just tried to run your `weights` computation on a test spatial object and got an error. I don't get an error if I try your `overlay` code with `fw` - you don't need to vectorise it because it already is - as long as `weights` is a vector of length five....

Comment: Your computation of `weights` only works if I `st_drop_geometry(...)` on the spatial data object first otherwise it tries to compute statistics on the geometry and fails. If I do that and get a simple length-five vector then all the overlay stuff works. How have you broken this?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and answers, I'll try to figure out how to get this to work with your clues.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Spacedman I could fix my problem by adding

`#deleting geometry from sn_sf_bind
sn_sf_bind2 <- st_drop_geometry(sn_sf_bind)`

before running `weights`. This got rid of the `geometry`column and resulted in `sn_sf_bind2`being a data.frame, which I could smoothly run through my code.